# how to i write the code for peek and Is empty in c#?

Tags: c#, stack

Nooby question I know but how do I write the code for a stack class Peek and Isempty? i have done `Push` and `Pop` but not sure about `Peek` and `IsEmpty`

```
public void Push(int value)
{
    array[top++] = value;
}

public int Pop()
{
    return array[--top];
}

public int Peek()
{
    /* ??? */
}

public bool IsEmpty()
{
    /* ??? */
}
```

Comment: Don't use an array for this. Also, there is already a stack class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Just like Broots, This way you have push and pop. For IsEmpty you can have an extention with count==0.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I'm guessing that the OP is learning programming, so this is more of an exercise.

Comment: @MatthewWatson If you are learning to drive a car, you don't start by making your own engine!  (I'm only half joking - I learned by doing, but that was 30 years ago, and I would have hoped teaching would have moved on by now).

Comment: And source code of stack https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs

Comment: @Neil If programmers aren't taught the basics of data structures, then I'm sad. (And I'd be very worried if my car's mechanic didn't know how its engine worked!)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, C# Stack is also an array.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Surely you learn that there is already a list,stack,dictionary component, rather than building your own.  These things are hard to do correctly, therefore don't roll your own, someone else has done the hard bits, you learn how to use them.

Comment: @Neil Sure, [if you just want to be a "code monkey"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18450/79464) - not that there's anything wrong with that! (tongue in cheek...)

Answer (score 1):

The stack will be empty if `top == 0`, so you can implement `IsEmpty()` like so:

```
    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return top == 0;
    }
```

Now `Peek()` can't work if the stack is empty. What to do in that case, you ask? The answer: Throw an exception:

```
    public int Peek()
    {
         if (IsEmpty())
             throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't Peek() an empty stack");

         return array[top-1]; // Topmost element is at 'top - 1'.
    }
```